# Unramified map to a simply connected surface

Tags: riemann-surfaces

I want to know why if f is an unramified covering to a simply connected surface then this function is an isomorphism?

Comment: Do you know the relationship between covering spaces and the fundamental group?

Comment: @Michael Albanese Yes,their deck transformation isomorphic to fundamental group.

Comment: Not quite. Coverings $X' \to X$ up to isomorphism correspond to conjugacy classes of subgroups of $\pi_1(X)$. If $X$ is simply connected, the only cover is $\operatorname{id}_X : X \to X$.

Comment: @Michael Albanese oh yes, with this fact we could conclude f is an isomorphism,but do we use unramify assumption directly?

Comment: Yes. In my comment above, when I say coverings, I mean unramified coverings, it's not true otherwise. For example, there is a ramified covering $T^2 \to S^2$ despite the fact that $S^2$ is simply connected.

Comment: Thank you very much